# Generating password saves for oldschool games

Tags: actionscript-3, passwords

I'm making oldschool-styled flash game and as it's so oldschool, I want it also to have password saves. Unfortunately I can't use usual solution - array of passwords and corresponding levels, one of which is to give hard time for guys on Arcadeprehacks and the other is that I want to make possible to save in-game and load with all score and lives.

About passwords, i.e. What I want

I need some solution to encode number values to string, which values are:

```
Lives - up to 2 digits
Score - 10 digits
Level number - 3 digits
```

It can also take 2 additional values which can be numbers or text, anything else will be converted to string.

It can't be converted to ANY string - only numbers and capital letters can be in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some basic decoder ring logic to generate your codes.  Zero becomes "F", one becomes "B", etc.  Anyone who is determined to hack your app will be able to translate it, but it will take some effort.

You can further obfuscate your data by throwing in useless data.  Throw in a random character in the third character position, for example, and then have your decoder always ignore the third character.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't kind of password what I have in mind. Go and play some NES classics like Adventure Island 4 to see what I meant.

Comment: You could use the crypto library to encrypt the result of puggsoy's algorithm using a private key embedded in your app.  You should then be able to decode any user-entered code using the private key you used to encrypt the data.  It's unlikely that you'd receive only alpha-numeric characters (especially only including upper case), but it would be relatively secure.  Someone would have to decompile your SWF to get your private key to be able to hack the code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep pass-code on a server side SQL.

Comment: Umm, seriously? That makes it impossible to play offline, firstly. You'd also need a server, plus write up some more code. All this for a password.

Comment: Most people don't play flash games offline and many already use a server for scores. If you already have a scoreboard this is a piece of cake to implement AND when somebody cracks it, you just change the passwords! :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you want is this:

```
var livesString:String = new String(lives);

var scoreString:String = new String(score);

for(var i:int = scoreString.length; i < 10; i++)
{
    scoreString = "0"+scoreString;
}

var lvlNumString:String = new String(lvlNum);

for(var i:int = lvlNumString.length; i < 3; i++)
{
    lvlNumString = "0"+lvlNumString;
}

var password:String = livesString+scoreString+lvlNumString;
```

That should give you a string which contains the data you want. For the two "additional values", simply add them onto `password` like this:

```
password += myVar.toString();
```

And then do this to make any text uppercase:

```
password.toUpperCase();
```

By the way, you said that the value for lives should be "up to 2 digits", but if you want it exactly 2 digits, just use a `for` loop similar to those above.

Comment: Ok, this is easiest way and I thought about it at first. However this has one major flaw - it's too easy to manipulate passwords to e.g. get 99 lives. I need some code, so I won't be able to manipulate passwords w/out knowing algorythm. Basically what I want to get is similar to ZD34FRGH65 - game will know that's (for example) mean 5 lives on level 3 with 5000 score, but user won't be able to manipulate it easily.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. See meddlingwithfire's suggestion commented on gladoscc's answer, it looks like a good idea. Remember to use `toUpperCase()` after it's been encrypted if you want all letters uppercase.

Comment: @Arnogh: Then use a crypto library. That's probably the most secure way.